# Extensões .pyc .pyd .pyo em Python

Tags: python, extensão

Tendo em vista que existem as determinadas extensões `.pyc`, `.pyd`, `.pyo` além do `.py` em [**Python**](https://www.python.org/), quais principais diferenças entre elas? O que cada uma representa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `.py`: normalmente o código fonte de entrada que você escreveu.
- `.pyc`: é o *bytecode* compilado. Se você importar um módulo o Python construirá um arquivo `*.pyc` que contém o *bytecode* para depois ficar mais fácil e mais rápido
- `.pyo`: é um arquivo *.pyc que foi criado com otimizações ativadas (-O)
- `.pyd`: [é basicamente um arquivo dll do Windows](http://Http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll).
- `.pyw`: Script Python para Windows. É executado com `pythonw.exe`
- `.pyx`: fonte Cython para ser convertido em C/C++
- `.pxd`: Cython *script* que é equivalente a um cabeçalho C/C++
- `.pxi`: MyPy *stub*
- `.pyi`: arquivo de *stub* ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/))
- `.pyz`: arquivo de *scripts* Python ([PEP 441](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/)); Contém *scripts* compactados Python (ZIP) em forma binária após o cabeçalho de *script* padrão Python
- `.pywz`: arquivo de *script* Python para MS-Windows ([PEP 441](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/)); Contém *scripts* compactados Python (ZIP) em forma binária após o cabeçalho de *script* padrão Python

Fontes em respostas do SO [do Bill Lynch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8822377/221800) e [do Devyn Collier Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032741/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

`.py` é normalmente o código escrito por você mesmo.

`.pyc` é o código binário compilado. Se você importa um modulo, Python vai gerar um arquivo *.pyc que contem o binario pra facilitar (e ser mais rapido) importar de novo o mesmo modulo.

`.pyo` igual ao arquivo `.pyc` mas criado quando as otimizacoes (-0) estavam ligadas.

`.pyd` é basicamente um arquivo dll do windows (mais infos [AQUI](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll))

Se quiser mais infos sobre a diferenca entre .pyo e .pyd, da uma olhada [aqui](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html)

Fonte: [SO gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8822377/3473971)